# Yii2 include datetimepicker in ActiveForm

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using Activeform and I need a custom field to insert datetime values.

I've found a possible solution myself with kartik DateTimePicker although it is much more complex than I wanted, anyway I don't know how to put the value in the model's attribute.

```
use kartik\datetime\DateTimePicker;


<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

// my working field using kartik library
<?= $form->field($model, 'course')->widget(\kartik\select2\Select2::className(),[
    'data' => $data,
    'language' => 'it',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a Course ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);?>

// the field I need to implement placing the result in $form->field($model, 'opening_date')
<?php //echo '<label style="position:absolute; top:5px; text-align:left;">Recording Time</label>';

echo '<label>Start Date/Time</label>';
echo DateTimePicker::widget([
        'name' => 'opening_date',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select operating time ...'],
    'convertFormat' => true,
    'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'd-M-Y g:i A',
        'startDate' => '01-Mar-2014 12:00 AM',
        'todayHighlight' => true
    ]
]);
?>
```

I accept also solutions offering a simpler way to show the field.

Comment: ummmm... the question isnt clear you might need to provide more detail, why are you using a separate input field to submit the values when you are already using the widget, which also does the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you are asking about using the widget with the model rather than calling it statically as you are currently copying the value to another ActiveForm field and then submitting it. If that is correct you can use the widget as a part of `ActiveForm` field so that you don't have to insert the date into a separate model input to submit and save, see below.

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'opening_date')->widget(
    DateTimePicker::class, 
    [
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select operating time ...'],
        'convertFormat' => true,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'd-M-Y g:i A',
            'startDate' => '01-Mar-2014 12:00 AM',
            'todayHighlight' => true
        ]
    ]
    );
?>
```

or you can pass the `$model` and `attribute` to your current code when calling the widget like below

```
echo DateTimePicker::widget(
    [
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'opening_date',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select operating time ...'],
        'convertFormat' => true,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'd-M-Y g:i A',
            'startDate' => '01-Mar-2014 12:00 AM',
            'todayHighlight' => true
        ]
    ]
);
```

You can either pass the `name`/`model` & `attribute` option see [details](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datetimepicker)

Comment: I tried with the first and this is the error: "Setting unknown property: yii\jui\DatePicker::convertFormat"

Comment: @gipsy sorry my bad i used `DatePicker` instead of `DateTimePicker` i just updated it in the answer change it to `DateTimePicker` and it will work

Comment: Thank you, now it works, it's just that the input is too complex, do you know other methods to create a model input field?

Comment: @gipsy what do you mean by **input is too complex?** and you can create with the above given methods when using a widget with input field , if its a normal field then you can also use the `yii\helpers\Html` class too , for creating model inputs. do mark the answer as correct if it worked for you